# jQuery / ajax filtering function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm building out a site that compares domain name prices and I need a little help with a particular function.

Presently, there is a section on the site where you can click on any of the tld buttons (.com, .net, etc) and it will then filter the divs around and show only those registrars with the pricing sorted low to high. That filter looks like this:

```
<li><a href="#portfolio-filter" title="generic TLD" class="orangebutton smallrectange" data-filter=".com">.com</a></li>
```

The results of the div will be something like this:

```
<div class="element com isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;">

    <div class="portfoliowrap">

        <div class="title">$0.99 - 1&amp;1<span class="titlearrow"></span></div>
        <div class="portfolioimage"><a href="images/latest-projects/larger-images/largeimage.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="Buy your domain at 1&amp;1"><img src="http://www.suitforthestars.com/css/images/94_godaddy.png" alt="Buy your domain at 1&amp;1"></a></div>
        <div class="text">valid until 2015-05-01 Usual price: $0.99 Limit 1 per customer. Additional domains are available at regular $14.99/year. valid until 2015-05-01.<span class="textarrow"></span></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I also have an ajax function setup that allows a user to search for a domain name, and it will tap an API and look to see if that domain is available or not. When they type in the domain, they have to type in the extension as well. (Example: news.com) And then the api returns the result as well as suggestions to the page should the domain name not be available.

What I am hoping to do as well, is using that same ajax function and jQuery, I'd like to be able to filter those divs down as well based on their domain and extension they typed in. I will know already what the domain extension is, because I parse that out in the api code. But what I would like to know is, how can I make it so that I can actually get those divs to filter based on that domain name as well.

The hoped expected result is one of two options. They can just click on the filter for their desired extension and it filters (that works!) or they can enter in a domain name and those divs are filtered down as well.

Any suggestions on how I could tie those two functions together? Greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Update:

Here is the jquery to check the domain and push it to the php script

```
$('#domain').live('keyup', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(App.search_type=='3') {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(function(){
            if($('#domain').val()!='') checkDomainAvailability();
            clearInterval(timer);
        }, 400);
    }   
});

function checkDomainAvailability() {
    var domain = $('#domain').val();

    $('.loading').addClass('loading_icon');

    if(domain!='') {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          data: 'domain='+domain,
          url: 'check/listeners/display_results.php',
          success: function(msg) {
            $('#results').html(msg);
            $('.loading').removeClass('loading_icon');
          }
        });     
    }
}
```

Here's the code for filtering the divs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $container = $('#portfolio-container')
    // initialize Isotope
        $container.isotope({
            // options...
            resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
            layoutMode : 'fitRows',
            itemSelector : '.element',
            animationEngine : 'best-available',

            // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
            masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 5 }
        });

        // update columnWidth on window resize
        $(window).smartresize(function(){
            $container.isotope({
            // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
            masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 5 }
            });
        });
        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){

                $container.isotope({
            // options...
                });
        });

        $('#portfolio-filter a').click(function(){
            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the javascript that you already have so we can modify it to suit your needs?

Comment: anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: The functions you provided handle user entering the domain name into a `#domain` box, and in your original question you mention that clicking on tld divs works also. So what seems to be the problem?

Comment: I'd like to make it so when the domain is entered, the divs filter like if they had been filtered by hitting one of the buttons. The site is checkdomainprices.com That will help you to better understand what I am after.

Comment: You didn't provide the code that hides the divs when user clicks one of the buttons. How can I mimic its behavior if i didn't see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you currently have the following setup:

Divs with domains have a class that corresponds to their *tld*, and *tld* buttons have a `data-filter` attribute that contains a selector that is used to filter the divs with domains.

To filter by a user-provided domain name you would have to add some attribute to your divs that would let us know which domain that div belongs to, for example:

```
<div class="element com isotope-item" style="..." data-domain="www.suitforthestars.com">
    <div class="portfoliowrap">
        <div class="title">...</div>
        <div class="portfolioimage">...<img src="http://www.suitforthestars.com/css/images/94_godaddy.png">...</div>
        <div class="text">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you could filter it like so:

```
$container.isotope({ filter: ".isotope-item[data-domain*='" + $('#domain').val() + "']" });
```

You can read about attribute selectors on the [official site of jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

Edit: The following seems to solve the problem clarified in chat:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    $('#portfolio-filter a').click(function(){
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });

    $('#domain').live('keyup', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(App.search_type != '3')
            return;
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            var val = $('#domain').val();
            var selector = val.replace(/^.*(\.\w+)$/, '$1';
            $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
            if(val)
                checkDomainAvailability();
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

Comment: So to clarify, by adding the data-domain filter, it would then allow the divs to be filtered when a user types in their domain?

Comment: @MrTechie exactly, to filter something you have to have enough data available

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but here's the question. When the divs start off they would have just data-domain="" in them. Then when a user types their domain in, the data-domain="" would have to change to something like data-domain="domain.com". How would that be done?

Comment: ah, I think I see and understand it now. The $container code is taking the value of what's entered into the domain box (#domain) and adding the value and then injecting it into the data-domain - correct?

Comment: @MrTechine Why would the domain change at runtime? As far as I can tell, most of your domains are created at startup, possibly even server-side (there are some divs that can be filtered wilh *tld* buttons, right?) and when a user asks you to create a new div, you just ask him what domain it should have and create it the same way you create the rest of the divs

Comment: @MrTechie No, the $container code is searching for `data-domain` that is already in the div to decide which divs to filter

Comment: could we push this to chat for a moment?

Comment: @MrTechie sure, why not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76846/discussion-between-mrtechie-and-sand).

Comment: thanks so much for understanding the issue and helping to rectify it. Definitely appreciated so much!